# UIView subclass in XIB doesn't display (drawRect: never called)

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I am designing a custom view controller in interface builder with a XIB file and I have a custom UIView subclass that I want to add to my view controller. Here is how I've put my custom view into the view controller:

[image: interface builder]

My `TonerEffectButtonView` class is a subclass of `UIView` (and has nothing to do with `UIButton`) and here is my code for it:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)prepareWithSelector:(SEL)selector onTarget:(id)targ withFilter:(GPUImageFilter*)filter{
    self.gpuImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:targ action:selector];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    selectedFilter = filter;
    [filter addTarget:self.gpuImageView];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

}
```

`initWithFrame:` is not called anyway as I'm creating the view through a XIB, and I don't need any customization in `initWithCoder:` so I haven't implemented it. I have a `GPUImageView` (that is a part of a library that I'm using) that I'm creating programatically inside my view, and adding camera input to it (if you ask what happens in the prepare method). Prepare method is called from outside, and *I've verified my UIView's frame is correct* when it is called. I have a breakpoint on `[super drawRect:rect];` and it never gets called, and when I run the program, my custom view is not displayed, nor does receive touch events (but prepare method **DOES** get called so the instance is created with the correct frame). It's like it has never been put there in interface builder. What could be the cause of this? I've seen many posts about this, and they mostly refer to creating views programatically and indicating problems with 'initWithFrame:'. But I have nothing to do with that method, and I want to use the interface builder/XIB couple, please don't advice me to create the view controller programatically. What could be the cause of it?

Thanks,

Can.

**UPDATE:** I can verify that `-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` is also not called in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. First, I've tried to add another instance programatically, and I've found out that it has autoresizing mask set to none, whereas my original instance has it set to W+H. This clue made me realize that in fact, I was forgetting to add my `GPUImageView` instance as a subview into my custom view. I've added it, and it worked.